# Suggested way to join filepaths in vim

Tags: vim

In python I will often do something like:

```
os.path.join('/some/path/', 'something', 'file.mov')
```

Or it can be done using `Path(...)`. What's the suggested way to do this in vim? For example, here is the way I'm currently creating a log file in the same directory as the script:

```
let log_file = expand('%:p:h') . '/file.log'
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've a [`lh#path#join()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/path.vim#L256) function in my library, but honestly... I never use it. In the end, it always comes down to string concatenation, and `/` always works, even on Windows. When I need to interact with external processes, I have other functions that correctly protect pathnames.

```
" Function: lh#path#join(pathparts, {path_separator}) {{{3
function! lh#path#join(pathparts, ...) abort
  let sep
        \ = (a:0) == 0                       ? '/'
        \ : type(a:1)==type(0) && (a:1) == 0 ? '/'
        \ : (a:1) == 1                       ? '\'
        \ : (a:1) =~ 'shellslash\|ssl'       ? (&ssl ? '\' : '/')
        \ :                                    (a:1)
  return join(a:pathparts, sep)
endfunction
```

Comment: thanks for this. That's a pretty neat library, been working on it for 12 years :).

Comment: but just to summarize, are you saying the approach I've used -- `expand('%:p:h') . '/file.log'` is an OK approach?

Comment: Your approach is perfect.

Comment: > _"That's a pretty neat library, been working on it for 12 years :)"_.
Thanks. It's much older actually. Hum... I see that the oldest file is from 2002, but I guess I should be able to find [traces of (deprecated) things](http://hermitte.free.fr/vim/idx-all.php#general) started in 2000 or 2001

Answer (score 3):

You can exploit the fact that `:p` adds a path separator if it's a directory:

```
let log_file = fnamemodify(expand('%:p:h'), ':p') .. 'file.log'
```

It's necessary to use `fnamemodify` because unfortunately we can't use `'%:p:h:p'`, because `:p` must be the first filename modifier, and `:h` removes the path separator.